# copy one role permission to another role

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have come across a scenario where I need to assign same set of permissions to multiple roles (Note: Roles are of same type like Regular-Regular etc).
For example: I have created three regular roles **"test_role_A"**, **"test_role_B"** and **"test_role_C"**. These three roles would have same permissions.
So I am wondering If I can **assign test_role_A role permissions to test_role_B and test_role_C at one go**.

**Is there any configuration in Liferay to do so?**

Answer (score 1):

After some research I observed that **RoleLocalServiceUtil** has methods like `reassignPermissions`, `mergePermissions` which are not fully satisfying my requirement.
However, I found that

> `ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermissions(resourceName,
>   roleName, scope, resourceActionBitwiseValue)`

would help my cause.
So here is the **beanshell script which will help you copy one role permission to another role of same type**.

```
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.ResourcePermission;
import java.util.List;
import com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Role;

long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(actionRequest);
Role fromRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, "<fromRoleName>");
List resourcePermissionList = ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getRoleResourcePermissions(fromRole.getRoleId());
//array of role names to which permissions needs to be copied
String [] copyToRoles = new String [] {"<ToRoleName1>", "<ToRoleName2>"};
for(String copyToRoleStr: copyToRoles){
    try{
        Role copyToRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, copyToRoleStr);
        try{
            for(int i=0;i< resourcePermissionList.size();i++){
                ResourcePermission rp = resourcePermissionList.get(i);
                ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermissions(rp.getName(), copyToRole.getName(), rp.getScope(), rp.getActionIds());
            }
            out.println("Successfully Assigned permissions of "+fromRole.getName()+" to "+copyToRole.getName());
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("Error occured while adding resource permission against role - "+copyToRoleStr+" : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error occured while fetching role - "+copyToRoleStr+" : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```